# Opening Angular Tree component in html file

Tags: html, angular

I am completly new to HTML/Angular.
I was following the basic tutorial from the angular website (https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs#basic-usage).

The problem I now have is that I do not understand how I call the tree in my HTML file with the statement from the website:

```html
<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>
```

To me it is not clear how the output class is important/defines the nodes that are in the tree and what the JSON "code" below the statement means. Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: my component.ts class

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'

})
export class App2Component {
  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  options = {};
}
```

and my component.html class

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
    <h2>Project 2 Demo</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      Status
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h3>{{title}}</h3>
      <tree-root [nodes]="[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'root1',
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'child1'
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'child2'
      }
    ]
  }
]" [options]="options"></tree-root>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, turns out you have to put the JSON stuff as a String into the "nodes" space, but I still do not understand why the export class has different childs/parents and what do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Architecture:-

1) `<body>` tag contains - root/parent component as `<app-root></app-root>` ie 
   parent module which contains a .ts,.html,.css,.spec files.
2) All other modules are inserted/loads inside `app.component.html` template 
    either by passing `selector` of `components` or loading component with 
   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`  and `data` is passed to `child components` 
    through `selector` of `child component(tree-root)` and `child component` 
   receive that `data` from `parent component` through `Input()`;

### app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<tree-root [nodes1]="nodes" [options1]="options"></tree-root>'
});

export class App {
  nodes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'root1',
      children: [
        { id: 2, name: 'child1' },
        { id: 3, name: 'child2' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'root2',
      children: [
        { id: 5, name: 'child2.1' },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: 'child2.2',
          children: [
            { id: 7, name: 'subsub' }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  options = {};
}
```

### tree-root.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-root',  <--- selector
  template: ''
});
export treeclassComponent implements OnInit{
@Input() nodes1: any  <---- Recieve input from app.component.ts(parent) here
@Input() options1: any  <----Recieve  input here

constructor(){}
ngOnInit() {
console.log(nodes);
console.log(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) and the [docs](https://angular.io/docs).

The JSON array describes the tree nodes and their children (see [here](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/options-1#nodes)).

The tree-component receives two input parameters (see [`@Input`](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)), which are provided by the `node` and `options` property.

The `node`s array delivers the information about the tree's node and children of the tree.

The tree-component will iterate over the given input array and creates the tree as you see it.

**Update:**

To create a tree you need to create an array of objects in your `*.component.ts`, like following:

```
this.nodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'root1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'child1'
            }, {
                id: 3,
                name: 'child2'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

The sample above is from [Angular2 Tree Nodes](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/options-1).

**Update 2:**

As I see you can simply use your previously posted html, because you declared the `nodes` array in your component:

`<tree-root [nodes]="nodes" [options]="options"></tree-root>`

Also you need to remove the `template` from your `@Component` definition, it should look like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
....
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! What exactly am I defining then in my export class? Because I thought that I define the structure there and would just call the class somehow?!

Comment: Well, I created these (copy pasted from website), but if I try to just call the html statement in my code its empty, I need to fill out the [nodes] with a new JSON for the childs parents. Now the questions is: Why do I need to fill out the [nodes] again with the desired structure if I already declared my structure in the export class?

Comment: Can you please add the code you tried so far to your question

Comment: yeah, I did. Sorry that it took a while!